# Remote video stream not playing after chrome updated to version 81.0.4044..111

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, twilio, android-chrome

We are using programmable video javascript SDK for video calling application.
We use H264 video codec.

In Android Chrome v80 local video and remote video works fine currently.

But in some android devices like Samsung Galaxy 9+, Realme, OnePlus having Chrome version 81 are facing issue of remote user's video not playing. Local video plays but when remote user turns ON his video, it shows **"No supported codec"** in SDK errro and **ERROR:    chromium : [ERROR:internal_decoder_factory.cc(56)] Trying to create decoder for unsupported format.**

I checked that Chrome version > 57 supports H264 video codec. It is still working in Chrome version 80. Then why it stopped working in Android Chrome v81.x?